# Gradle: Build getting failed with exception: org/gradle/ api/internal/ExternalProcessStartedListener

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build, sts

I am new to gradle and not able to debug the following issue whenever I am trying to build any project.
I am using the command  (gradle clean build)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  org/gradle/api/internal/ExternalProcessStartedListener

[image]

[image]

I am using gradle version 7.4.2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `gradle clean build -x test --stacktrace`.

Comment: Also try running clean alone and then in another run only build. In case tasks are not properly connected it can happen that tasks related to build do run and clean runs in between. It's also a bad practice in general to run clean and build together.

Comment: Had done clean and build actions  separately but still facing the same issue...added the stack trace for the same...i have even deleted the demon folder under .gradle but it is of no use.